# Como os assinantes do evento são executados após a chamada?

Tags: c#, multithreading, eventos

Eu estou tentando fazer uma representação visual da geração de números aleatórios usando `UWP`. Basicamente, existem retângulos X em uma tela, cada um representa um número, então o primeiro retângulo é 0, o segundo 1 e assim por diante. A classe que representa esses retângulos possui estes atributos:

```
public class Representer
{
    public int TimesChosen { get; set; }
    public int NumberRepresented { get; set; }
    public double CurrentProportion { get; set; }
    public double RectangleWidth { get; set; }
    public Rectangle Rect { get; set; }
    .
    .
}
```

Cada vez que um número é gerado, o Representante correspondente obtém a variável "`TimesChosen`" incrementada em 1. Este acesso é feito através de um dicionário na classe Manager:

```
public class Manager
{
    public Canvas CanvasManaged { get; set; }
    public double NumbersGenerated { get; set; }

    public readonly int Range;
    public Dictionary<int, Representer> Representers = new Dictionary<int, Representer>();

 .
 .
 }
```

Quando um número é gerado, a altura desses retângulos deve ser atualizada para a proporção correspondente, por exemplo, se eu tiver 5 retângulos e todos eles tiverem seus números gerados uma quantidade igual de tempo, a proporção de todos os retângulos é 20%, e assim a altura deve ser de 20% da tela. A maneira que eu estou tentando atualizar toda a proporção de retângulos e suas alturas é através de um evento. Toda vez que um número é gerado, o gerente gera um evento que informa todos os retângulos que devem ser atualizados:

```
public async void GenerateNumber(TextBlock Iterations)
    {
        Random Random = new Random();

        while (true)
        {
            int Number = Random.Next(this.Range);
            this.NumbersGenerated += 1;
            Representers[Number].TimesChosen += 1;

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                OnNumberGenerated();
            });

            Iterations.Text = this.NumbersGenerated.ToString();

        }

    }

    public virtual void OnNumberGenerated()
    {
        NumberGenerated?.Invoke(this, new ManagerArgs { NumbersGenerated = this.NumbersGenerated, CanvasManaged = this.CanvasManaged });
    }
```

A implementação do `OnNumberGenerated` nos Representantes é:

```
public async void OnNumberGenerated(object source, ManagerArgs e)
    {

        this.CurrentProportion = this.TimesChosen / e.NumbersGenerated;

        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await e.CanvasManaged.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                this.Rect.Height = e.CanvasManaged.Height * this.CurrentProportion;
                this.Rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, Convert.ToByte(255 * this.CurrentProportion), Convert.ToByte(255 * (1 - this.CurrentProportion)), 0));
            });
        });
    }
```

O problema é que o desempenho é realmente ruim, por exemplo, se eu tenho 1000 retângulos, a taxa de atualização é de cerca de 10 retângulos / segundo. Isso me levou a pensar: de que maneira as implementações de `OnNumberGenerated` estão sendo chamadas após o evento ser gerado? Existe uma maneira de fazer essas implementações para serem chamadas de forma assíncrona ou em `threads`? Existe uma maneira de melhorar o desempenho do programa?